# WIN32 send data in socket function arg error

Tags: c, winapi, winsock

working on a program using WIN32 API i want the program to take data from functions that gather certain info in the system and pass argument to DbgPrint function as char and i want that char to be sent to that ip and port how to get the job done without any errors in function args
my code is just like:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void socketfnt (auto *ipaddr, auto *portn, char*msg){
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET s;
struct sockaddr_in server;

printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}

printf("Initialised.\n");

//Create a socket
if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
}

printf("Socket created.\n");
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddr);
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( portn );

//Connect to remote server
if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    puts("connect error");
    return 1;
}

puts("Connected");
message = msg;
if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
{
    puts("Send failed");
    return 1;
}
puts("Data Send\n");

return 0;
}


void DbgPrint(char *msg){
socketfnt("192.168.1.6","4444", msg);
}
```

compiler show errors like

```
fff.c:6:23: error: storage class specified for parameter 'ipaddr'
fff.c:6:37: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'portn' [- 
Wimplicit-int]
void socketfnt (auto *ipaddr, auto *portn, char*msg){
```

can you guys show me how to pass arguments to **socketfnt** function in a right way
,regards

Comment: Misuse of `auto` keyword in function parameters.

Comment: So what the right data type in function parameter in this situation

Comment: `inet_addr()` takes a `const char*` parameter and `htons()` takes a `uint16_t`.
So, I'd do: `void socketfnt (const char *ipaddr, uint16_t portn, char*msg)`

Comment: Then you must correct the call to (for instance) `socketfnt("192.168.1.6",4444, msg);` (since the second parameter is an integer not a string).

Comment: shows /include/winsock2.h:997:34: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'
   WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE int WSAAPI send(SOCKET s,const char *buf,int len,int flags);
                                  ^

Comment: `auto` is a storage class specifier in C, that no-one uses, because it's the default. It can only be used in variable declarations, not in function parameter lists. The meaning of `auto` changed in C++11 from a storage class specifier to automatic type deduction. Automatic type deduction is not available in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `auto` for parameters to non-lambda functions.  You need to use proper data types.

You are also leaking resources.

Try this instead:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void socketfnt (const char *ipaddr, uint16_t portn, const char *msg)
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    puts("\nInitializing Winsock...");

    int ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d\n", ret);
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Initialized.\n");

    //Create a socket
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    puts(Socket created.\n");

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddr);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(portn);

    if (server.sin_addr.s_addr == INADDR_NONE)
    {
        puts("Invalid IP address.\n");
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Could not connect socket : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");

    int size = strlen(msg);
    while (size > 0)
    {
        ret = send(s, msg, size, 0);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            printf("Could not send data : %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(s);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        msg += ret;
        size -= ret;
    }

    puts("Data Send\n");

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}

void DbgPrint(const char *msg)
{
    socketfnt("192.168.1.6", 4444, msg);
}
```